# Thunderbird keyboard shortcut to switch dictionary language

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird, language, spell-check

As a non-American I write emails in multiple languages. In the newest releases of Thunderbird the add-on [Dictionary Switcher](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/dictionary-switcher/) is no longer supported, so I would like to just add a shortcut for cycling through installed dictionary languages.

I am aware of the add-on [Automatic Dictionary](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/automatic-dictionary-switching/), but that only works on remembered contacts.

I have the [KeyConfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension:_Thunderbird) add-on, but I can't find a working formula for changing dictionary language in the compose window. I  have tried these three:

```
var SD='spellchecker.dictionary'; 
try{var sd=navigator.preference(SD); 
  sd=prompt('Spelling dictionary',sd); 
  if(sd!=null && sd!='') {
    navigator.preference(SD,sd);
  }
} catch (e) {alert('Permission to change the dictionary was denied');}
```

And

```
changeLanguage({ target: "en-US", __noSuchMethod__: function() { } });
```

And

```
Services.prefs.setCharPref("spellchecker.dictionary", "en-US");
```

Does anybody know code that works or potentially a different solution? I am on Ubuntu.